# "Not Implemented" error when placing page guard before adding VEH

Tags: c++, windows, exception

I get a "Not Implemented" exception from the following piece of code whenever I place a page guard on a function before adding a vectored execption handler:

```
__except (_seh_filter_exe(GetExceptionCode(), GetExceptionInformation()))
```

My code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

void Test()
{
    printf("Success!\n");
}

LONG WINAPI VEH(EXCEPTION_POINTERS * ExceptionPointers)
{
    printf("Next: 0x%08X\n", ExceptionPointers->ContextRecord->Eip);

    if(STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION == ExceptionPointers->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode)
    {
        ExceptionPointers->ContextRecord->EFlags |= 0x100;
        return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
    }
    if(STATUS_SINGLE_STEP == ExceptionPointers->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode)
    {
        DWORD Old;
        VirtualProtect(&Test, 0x1000, PAGE_EXECUTE | PAGE_GUARD, &Old);
        return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
    }

    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

int main()
{
    DWORD Old;

    VirtualProtect(&Test, 0x1000, PAGE_EXECUTE | PAGE_GUARD, &Old);
    AddVectoredExceptionHandler(TRUE, VEH);
    Test();
    printf("Out!\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Swap

```
VirtualProtect(&Test, 0x1000, PAGE_EXECUTE | PAGE_GUARD, &Old);
AddVectoredExceptionHandler(TRUE, VEH);
```

Into

```
AddVectoredExceptionHandler(TRUE, VEH);
VirtualProtect(&Test, 0x1000, PAGE_EXECUTE | PAGE_GUARD, &Old);
```

And it works. Why is that?

Comment: What is this for anyways?

Comment: I wonder if `PAGE_EXECUTE | PAGE_GUARD` is the problem. You are combining executable bit with guard page. Sounds contradictory to me.

Comment: I was trying to see if I could implement something like CFG that checks if the instructions executed are within the bounds of an allowed function. I did not think that idea trough, but it's beside the point really. I'm just curious as to why this specific error occurs

Comment: @TanveerBadar Why would that be a problem? Especially considering the fact that if I flip those 2 calls, it works well (Meaning it does what you'd expect it will)

Comment: Guard pages are used to implement a growable stack. A side-effect of this code is that your stack can no longer grow.